# Can AWS Step function async run bash script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, amazon-ec2, aws-step-functions

I have a step function which defined with jobs definition in java.

I wanna add an async run bash script which trying to move the data from efs to s3 bucket. 
What I did:
1. Login the the ec2 instance which has efs data mounted;
2. run the data move bash script;

The disadvantage of it is I need daily manually run this script. So, I wanna know if there is a way to run this script from step function since all the efs data are generated from the job submitted to this step function.

Comment: Can you clarify? You want to run a script on some instance(s) based on a trigger from step function?

Comment: Hello, try to run a lambda with python and the os module there. Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4256153/7348119

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot directly however the following should work for you:

- Step to call a Lambda function
- Have Lambda run a [Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html)
- Wait for run command to be completed successfully, before returning success or error.

Either write your own Run Command Document or instead take a look at `AWS-RunShellScript` document.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll check it by your suggestion.